# Adding feature to k-means

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use k-means clustering to classify text documents. Is it possible to take a set of documents tfidf vectorize them and perform the computation then add more documents to be classified?

This is what I have so far

```
true_k = 4
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)
```

How would I add more documents to X? Because I would like to pickle X and save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is pretty simple (controrary to the accepted answer, which suggests that this is complex - it is not). Just concatenate your data, and reuse **the same vectorizer** (if you create new one, or refit the old one, as suggested in the accepted answer, it will **change its estimations** and consequently you will get different feature spaces), thus you have to pickle it too

```
true_k = 4
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)
```

now you get new data, documents2 and simply do

```
X2 = vectorizer.transform(documents2)
X = np.vstack((X, X2))
model.fit(X) # optimally you would start from the previous solution, but sklearn does not yet support it
```

However, remember that this assumes that your first batch of documents was already **representative for the whole dataset**. In other words, you will limit yourself to words from the first documents, and also the idf normalization will not be refitted. You could actually remove both limitations, but you would have to implement your own - online tfidf vectorizer, which can update its estimates. It is not hard to do, but you would have to (after each new batch of documents) also update previous ones (as idf part would change). Easier solution would be to instead keep only countvectorizer and update it, and compute "idf" part independently and apply it on top (just before kmeans).

Comment: I tried this and it worked. Thank you for showing me whats possible. I'm new to the ML world.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `X` feature matrix if of the shape `[n_docs, n_features`]. Hence, if you create a new feature matrix with new documents you would have to make sure that the new feature matrix (`X2`) has exactly the same features as `X`. I cannot image a application where this is feasible.

But if you know that both have the same feature space, you can use `scipy.sparse.vstack` to append the new documents to your feature matrix:

```
from scipy.sparse import vstack

X = vstack((X, X2))
```

EDIT: To ensure the same feature space in `X2`, you can use the `vocabulary` keyword argument in `TfidfVectorizer`, e.g.:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
vectorizer = vectorizer.fit(documents)
X = vectorizer.transform(documents)

# do whatever with X

new_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', vocabulary=vectorizer.vocabulary_)
X2 = vectorizer.fit_transform(new_documents)

X = vstack((X, X2))
```

That means, on top of saving `X` you also need to store `vectorizer.vocabulary_`.

Comment: Is there something else I could use to accomplish this? I'm trying todo dynamic text classification. Basically take a set of documents then classify them into classifications then get new documents and add them to those existing classifications?

Comment: If this is what you want to accomplish, you can also train a `pipeline` with a `TfidfVectorizer` and a `KMeans` model and pickle that one. After unpickeling you just apply the trained `pipeline` model to new documents. See for instance [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#building-a-pipeline).

Comment: this is not correct use of vectorizer, it will not have the same feature space

Comment: yes, it will - if your specify the vocabulary as mentioned above.